# How to save the the data processed by this PHP code to a CSV or TXT file

Tags: php, csv, text-files

I got the following php code that currently process a txt file with data that looks like this per line (Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies) and I'm reformatting this to use it with my database.

What I'd like to do is save the output data to a CSV or TXT file instead or printing it in my browser as it currently does. Notice that I have 3 print sections within the script.

Any help or advise will be much appreciated.

```
set_time_limit(0);

//read and process txt.txt
$file_handle = fopen("txt.txt", "rb");

$j = 0;

while (!feof($file_handle)){

    $line = fgets($file_handle);

    $parts = explode('>', $line);

    if(count($parts) == 1 ){

        $parts[0] = trim($parts[0]);

        $db[$j] = array("CatName"=>$parts[0], "CatID"=>$j+1, "PID"=>0, "Level"=>1);

        print $db[$j]["CatName"]."\t".$db[$j]["CatID"]."\t".$db[$j]["PID"]."\t".$db[$j]["Level"]."\r\n";


    } else {

        $i =0;

        $no = count($parts);

        $t = $no-1;

        while($t != -1){

            $parts[$t] = trim( $parts[$t] );

            $t = $t-1;
        }

        $k = $j-1;

        while( $i != $j){

            while($k > -1){

                if( strcmp($parts[$i], $db[$k]["CatName"]) == 0 ){

                    $flag = 1;

                }

                $k = $k-1;

            }

            if($flag == 1){

                if(strcmp($parts[$no-2], $db[$i]["CatName"]) == 0){

                    $found = $i;

                }

            }

            $i = $i+1;

        }

        if($flag == 1){

            $db[$j] = array("CatName"=>$parts[$no-1], "CatID"=>$j+1, "PID"=>$db[$found]["CatID"], "Level"=>$no);

            print $db[$j]["CatName"]."\t".$db[$j]["CatID"]."\t".$db[$j]["PID"]."\t".$db[$j]["Level"]."\r\n";


        }

        if($flag == 0 && $no == 1){

            $db[$j] = array("CatName"=>$parts[$no-1], "CatID"=>$j+1, "PID"=>0, "Level"=>$no);

            print $db[$j]["CatName"]."\t".$db[$j]["CatID"]."\t".$db[$j]["PID"]."\t".$db[$j]["Level"]."\r\n";


        }

    }

    $j = $j+1;

    $flag = 0;

}

fclose($file_handle);
```

BTW: I have already used stings to replaced the print statements and then save their outputs to my csv file, but it wont work, it only returns empty values.
Example used:

```
//print $db[$j]["CatName"]."\t".$db[$j]["CatID"]."\t".$db[$j]["PID"]."\t".$db[$j]["Level"]."\r\n";
$csv_data .= $db[$j]["CatName"]."\t".$db[$j]["CatID"]."\t".$db[$j]["PID"]."\t".$db[$j]["Level"]."\r\n";
```

Comment: See [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: will look into it, however the page does not give a good example on how to use Output Control properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is take what this script currently outputs and save it, you can either use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) as [Jared Farrish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451969/jared-farrish) mentioned, or replace your `print` statements with statements concatenating to a string variable.

For example, you could declare an empty string like this:

```
$output = '';
```

... and then replace each `print` statement with a [concatenation assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) like `.=`:

```
// Instead of:
print $db[$j]["CatName"]."\t".$db[$j]["CatID"]."\t".$db[$j]["PID"]."\t".$db[$j]["Level"]."\r\n";

// Replace with:
$output .= $db[$j]["CatName"]."\t".$db[$j]["CatID"]."\t".$db[$j]["PID"]."\t".$db[$j]["Level"]."\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonathan, I have already used stings to replaced the print statements, but it wont work, it only returns empty values

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. So at the end of the code, $csv_data is still empty? Are you initializing it before use?